# Terraform Kubernetes - Remove annotation

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I'm trying to configure AWS EKS & Fargate. By default, the CoreDNS add-on is configured to run on EC2 nodes hence I have to remove it (annotation) so that Fargate (worker node) can pick it up, this step is officially stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html). This whole thing should be automated using Terraform. The said step can be achieved using [Terraform's Kubernetes provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs). However, I can't find any article/doc saying how to target certain values in `ignore_annotations`.

On the EKS & Fargate doc, it says I have to run the ff command to remove annotation:

```bash
kubectl patch deployment coredns \
    -n kube-system \
    --type json \
    -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/metadata/annotations/eks.amazonaws.com~1compute-type"}]'
```

and in the Terraform Kubernetes provider [doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs), the configuration should look like the ff:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  ignore_annotations = [
    "^service\\.beta\\.kubernetes\\.io\\/aws-load-balancer.*",
  ]
}
```

I tried the ff configuration but it didn't work (annotation is not removed):

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
    args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", module.eks.cluster_id]
    command     = "aws"
  }

  ignore_annotations = [
    "eks\\.amazonaws\\.com\\/compute-type",
  ]
}
```

perhaps I have the `ignore_annotations` value wrong?

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Was there an error?

Comment: The annotation is not ignored/removed.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be removed with the `ignore_annotations`. I think it only serves the purpose of telling Terraform to ignore those as they are not present in other K8s resources. I am actually not convinced that the K8s provider has a way to do a `patch` action just be adding a parameter to the provider configuration.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the use of `ignore_annotations`, it meant ignoring, not removing. It seems like the `k8s patch` is a highly requested feature but ain't available right now. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/723